# NumberFormatException while converting string to Integer

Tags: java, android

I'm getting integers of two EditText and on one of them textWatch is applied, multiplying them and setting text to another EditText. it normally works fine but when one of edit field become empty while hitting backspace app crashes.

```
protected final TextWatcher getValueWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        int unitPrice = Integer.parseInt(unitPriceEdit.getText().toString());
        if (s.length() > 0)
        totalPriceEdit.setText(String.valueOf(qty * unitPrice));
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at 
java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334) at 
com.example.fani.project.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:90) 
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7679) at 
android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7739)
```

Comment: what kind of exception do you get? probably a NumberFormatException?

Comment: could you please post the logcat..

Comment: yes its is NumberFormatException.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.example.fani.project.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:90)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7679)
            at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7739)

Comment: I think you should check the length of string before converting it to integer...because if u try to convert an empty string....it will raise NumberFormatException..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code as below

```
protected final TextWatcher getValueWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      if (s.length() > 0){
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        int unitPrice = Integer.parseInt(unitPriceEdit.getText().toString());
        totalPriceEdit.setText(String.valueOf(qty * unitPrice));
      }
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Check the length of your string before parsing it..

Comment: works like a charm Thank you So much and sorry for posting a silly question but I'm a beginner

Comment: Glad that it helped.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your onTextChanged():

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length() > 0){
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        int unitPrice = Integer.parseInt(unitPriceEdit.getText().toString());
        totalPriceEdit.setText(String.valueOf(qty * unitPrice));
    }
}
```

Comment: works like a charm Thank you So much and sorry for posting a silly question but I'm a beginner

Comment: Good to know, can you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

null pointer error occurs due to `s.length > 0`
Change this in your code.

```
 if (s.length() > 0)
    totalPriceEdit.setText(String.valueOf(qty * unitPrice));
 }
```

TO

```
if(s != null){

   if (s.length() > 0)
    totalPriceEdit.setText(String.valueOf(qty * unitPrice));
  }
}
```